# How to count and build string by distinct value

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need some script to the following on teradata to get distinct ID from the below table - COLUMN ID, then count of the column device by distinct column ID, then SUBSTRING out into a new column from column name the AB, BEGOOD, ONSITE

```
ID        Device      Name
11123503     500    AB_BEGOOD_ONSITE_VOOM
11123503     700    AB_LATESTMODEL_ONSITE_VOOM
11123503     900    AB_LATESTMODEL_ONSITE_VOOM
11123503     870    AB_LATESTMODEL_ONSITE_VOOM
11123503     489    AB_LATESTMODEL_ONSITE_VOOM
11132048     134    AB_BEGOOD_ONSITE_VOOM
11132048     342    AB_BEGOOD_ONSITE_VOOM
11132048     545    AB_BEGOOD_ONSITE_VOOM
11132048     847    AB_BEGOOD_ONSITE_VOOM
```

[image]

Comment: What is the sql that you have tried so far?

Comment: Your data doesn't macth your expected result. Hint: have a look at the `STRTOK` function.